# [] reduce with anonymous function in Perl 6

Tags: syntax, functional-programming, raku

We can use `reduce` with a `sub` with two arguments, putting it in double brackets:

```perl6
> sub mysum { $^a + $^b }
> [[&mysum]] 1,3,5
9
```

But what if we want to use an anonymous function instead?

Both following variants produce a compile error:

```perl6
> [[&{ $^a + $^b }]] 1,3,5
> [[{ $^a + $^b }]] 1,3,5
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are not allowed to have any spaces in that form of reduce.

```perl6
> [[&({$^a+$^b})]] 1, 3, 5
9
```

This is so that it is more obvious that it is a reduce, and not an array declaration.

```perl6
> [ { $^a + $^b }, { $^a * $^b } ].pick.(3,5)
8 | 15
```

---

The double `[[…]]` is just an extension of allowing any function to be used as an infix operator.

Note that you must use `&(…)` in this feature, when not talking about a named function `&foo`, or an already existing infix operator.

```perl6
> 3 [&( { $^a + $^b } )] 5
8
```

This is sort-of an extension of using `[…]` for bracketing meta operators like `Z` and `=`

```perl6
> @a [Z[[+]=]] 1..5
> @a Z[[+]=] 1..5
> @a Z[+=] 1..5
> @a Z+= 1..5
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why that doesn't work. But there's always:

```
say reduce { $^a + $^b }, 1,3,5 # 9
```

I'm guessing you knew that <strike>but it's all I've got for tonight</strike>. :)

I've now moved my comment here and expanded it a bit before I go to sleep.

The TTIAR error means it fails to parse the reduce as a reduce. So I decided to take a quick gander at [the Perl 6 grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp).

I searched for "reduce" and quickly deduced that it must be failing to match [this regex](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L4184-L4209).

While that regex might be only 20 or so lines long, and I recognize most of the constructs, it's clearly not trivial. I imagine there's a way to use `Grammar::Debugger` and/or some other grammar debugging tool with the Perl 6 grammar but I don't know it. In the meantime, you must be a bit of a regex whiz by now, so you tell me: why doesn't it match? :)

## Update

With Brad's answer to your question as our guide, the answer to my question is instantly obvious. The [first line of the regex proper](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L4187) (after the two variable declarations) directly corresponds to the "no spaces" rule that Brad revealed:

```
<?before '['\S+']'>
```

This is an assertion that the regex engine is positioned immediately before a string that's of the form `[...]` where the `...` is one or more non-space characters. (`\s` means space, `\S` means non-space.)

(Of course, I'd have been utterly baffled *why* this non-space rule was there without Brad's answer.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I knew that, the question was about the `[]` syntax.